# User login using modal that stays open on error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5.1

I am trying to use a modal for user login. Logging in works but the form just closes when I type in a wrong password. The form is pretty basic with an id of "idForm." Below is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('/auth/login') }}",
            data: $("#idForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                location.reload();
            }
          });

      e.preventDefault(); 
  });
```

});

Based on Laravel 5.1, I know if there is a problem, it sends $errors back to the same page but I don't know how to retrieve it within the same modal using Ajax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the success function executes when there has been a successful ajax call, not necessarily when the user logs in successfully.

I don't know what kind of data is returned from the server, you'll have to check the data object.

```
success: function(data){
    if( ...check the data object to see if login successful... ) location.reload();
    else{
        // do stuff for failed login
    }
}
```

Comment: what would be the best way of finding that out and generally how would things generally look like in the else statement?

Comment: do `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`  on the first line of the success function.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, I guess this task was more over my head than I thought. I see the output from that alert box but still have no idea what to really look for in it.

Comment: will you still be able to help me a little further by any chance?

Comment: sure. post the output from the alert and i'll take a look as soon as i can.

Comment: Right now it just shows me the DOM for the page that the modal was initiated on. I do not see any form data from the login form itself. My browser is not letting me copy/past it for some reason.

Comment: that's odd.. can you zip the whole thing up and upload it somewhere so I can look at the whole code?